# Why I get a memory address using lambda function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I´m new in Python and I guess this is a very simple question because I can´t find an answer. I have this code:

```
Celsius = [39.2, 36.5, 37.3, 37.8]
Fah = map(lambda x: (float(9)/5)*x + 32, Celsius)
print(Fah)
```

I expect to get:

```
>>> [102.56, 97.700000000000003, 99.140000000000001, 100.03999999999999]
```

But I get:

```
>>> <map object at 0x000000000909CA20>
```

Comment: In python 3.X `map` returns a `map object` which is an iterator like object. If you want to get a `list()`, you need to call the list function on your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` returns a generator, to view it convert it to list:

```
Fah = map(lambda x: (float(9)/5)*x + 32, Celsius)
print(list(Fah))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
print(Fah)
```

to:

```
print(list(Fah))
```